# How to ship a vue component with associated vuex and css with it so that i can use it in different project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, webpack-style-loader, webpack-loader

Hi i have 2 projects one is `core` and another is `plugins` [both project have its own folder and **package.js**] my intention is plugin must work without compiling from `core` independently.

**Project structure:** only rendered view not folders

```
<core project> <!-- core project or project 1 -->
   <iframe src="plugin/dist/index.html"> <!-- plugins project or project 2 -->
<core project>
```

**Now i'm in such a situation where i need to completely port `css` and `vuex` store into plugin**

Here is how i'm setting core component into loaded `body` object so that it can be used in plugins

```
let coreComp1 = import('/path');
parent.document.components = coreComp1; // similar to jquery $('body').data('components',coreComp1)
```

now in plugins i can access like this

```
<compx></compx>
...
{
components:{
  compx: ()=> parent.document.components //<-- observe this line
}
}
```

**Now component of `core` render correctly without `css` and `vuex` methods**

`vuex` methods in my core component is like shown below

```
 {
   methods:{
      doAssetUpdate(){
         this.updateAssets().then(...)  <!-- **getting error:** Cannot read properties of undefined -->
      },
      ...mapActions("assets", ["updateAssets"]),
   }
 }
```

**Question**: keeping above scenario in mind how to ship component with used `vuex` and `css` with it.

Please help me thanks in advance !!